# Bachelor thesis going out of hand, need help

Tags: fluid-dynamics, preconditioning, conjugate-gradient, multigrid

I am currently working on my bachelor thesis, which aims to enhance the multigrid preconditioned conjugate gradient algorithm proposed by Tatebe in 1993 using Deep Learning.

Currently, I am implementing it on a 2D lid-driven cavity problem. However, I have encountered an issue where the algorithm from Tatebe is producing very high residuals, even without integrating the deep learning aspect. Initially, when I introduced my own idea for the thesis, it seemed to work, but upon further examination, I realized that I had miscalculated the residuals, leading me to believe it was functioning correctly.

I have been attempting to resolve this issue for weeks now, and I find myself somewhat desperate. However, I understand that encountering challenges is part of the research process.

Today, I made a significant discovery. When I converted the conjugate gradient algorithm to a multigrid preconditioned steepest descent, the residuals showed remarkable improvement. It seems that calculating the beta with the multigrid component may be causing numerical instability in the system.

Now, I believe I have made a valuable discovery with the multigrid preconditioned steepest descent approach. However, my bachelor thesis focuses on enhancing a multigrid preconditioner with deep learning to reduce the number of iterations required for the conjugate gradient method.

Should I discuss this with my supervisor and inquire about shifting from the conjugate gradient to steepest descent? The topic is relatively underexplored, and it could offer a novel contribution to the field. However, I am uncertain about how to proceed.

I would greatly appreciate any input or advice you can provide, as my current perspective feels somewhat limited.

Best regards

Comment: You're supposed to have regular meetings with your supervisor regarding progress and direction. The fact that you are asking the above question suggests you are not having such meetings and that your supervisor is not doing his job of supervising you. I have had pretty terrible experiences in academia so I wouldn't be surprised if that was the case though. In either case you should try and set up a meeting and discuss things, ideally prepare a small presentation illustrating what you mentioned here with some numerical experiments. Generally the expectations of bsc theses are not big though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic on Computational Science SE. There is [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/), which would be right on-topic; however, I would encourage you to first search for similar questions, as there are quite lot of them devoted to student-advisor interactions in various difficult and not-so-difficult situations.